# How do I create an AR app with Unity for Samsung Galaxy A12?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arcore, samsung-galaxy

I am trying to create an AR application with Unity for my Android phone: Samsung Galaxy A12, but somehow it does not work.

This is my situation:

- I use Unity 2021.1.0f1
- I have connected the phone to my laptop on which I am running Unity
- I have selected Developer Mode on my phone
- I have the Android packages, ARCore, ARKit XR Plugin and AR Foundation (which I think I do not use) installed in Unity
- I use Vuforia
- I use ARCore which probably causes the problem
- My scene contains only directional light, an ARCamera, Image Target and a sphere
- My scene works when I run it on my laptop and does what it should do (just hit play, NOT build & run on my laptop) which is showing the sphere on a piece of paper I hold in front of the camera.

When I Build & Run the Unity scene, I get four error messages:

1:

```
ARMv7 is not compatible with the ARCore version included when using the "Include ARCore Library" option in the VuforiaConfiguration. To use an older version of ARCore which supports ARMv7, please include ARCore manually in your project instead.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:Log (System.Action`1<string>,string)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:Error (string)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:LogHighSeverity (Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResult)
PlayerSettingsValidationTask:Execute ()
BuildObserver/<>c:<OnPreprocessBuild>b__3_0 (Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>:ForEach (System.Action`1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>)
BuildObserver:OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

2:

```
Error building Player: ARMv7 is not compatible with the ARCore version included when using the "Include ARCore Library" option in the VuforiaConfiguration. To use an older version of ARCore which supports ARMv7, please include ARCore manually in your project instead.
```

3:

```
    Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 0 seconds (318 ms)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

4:

```
    UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002ca] in <0e11587263324259967daac4d577d226>:0 
  at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <0e11587263324259967daac4d577d226>:0 
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

And one warning:

```
Vulkan support is currently experimental in Vuforia Engine and therefore not fully supported.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning (object)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:Log (System.Action`1<string>,string)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:Warn (string)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResultExtensions:LogHighSeverity (Vuforia.EditorClasses.PlayerSettingsValidationResult)
PlayerSettingsValidationTask:Execute ()
BuildObserver/<>c:<OnPreprocessBuild>b__3_0 (Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>:ForEach (System.Action`1<Vuforia.EditorClasses.VuforiaLifeCycleTask>)
BuildObserver:OnPreprocessBuild (UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

What I think might be the issue:

- Maybe the Samsung Galaxy A12 is not compatible with Vuforia. I can upload a scene without importing Vuforia. Should I use an older version of Vuforia?

My question is:

- How do I run an Unity AR scene on a Samsung Galaxy A12?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: install an older version of Vuforia! I think I downloaded Vuforia 9